# Is it possible to get "WITH EXECUTE AS " working under "dbo user/Administrator login" permissions (VIEW SERVER STATE needed)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

The problem can be emulated this way:

```
DECLARE @C1 BIGINT,@C2 BIGINT;
PRINT SUSER_NAME()+ ' '+ USER_NAME();
SELECT @C1=transaction_id from sys.dm_tran_current_transaction (nolock)
PRINT @C1
EXECUTE AS USER = 'dbo';
PRINT SUSER_NAME()+ ' '+ USER_NAME();
SELECT @C2=transaction_id from sys.dm_tran_current_transaction (nolock)
PRINT @C2
REVERT;
```

Called from 'Administrator' login (db owner, linked to dbo user) returns:

```
Administrator dbo
2209599
Administrator dbo
Msg 297, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
The user does not have permission to perform this action.
```

The same user but different results. Why?

**Details:**

I have a SP that contains select from sys.dm_os_sys_info and therefore this SP's caller should have VIEW SERVER STATE permissions.

I have modified SP header with "WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER". Owner is standard 'dbo' database user linked to 'Administrator' server login. Administrator is a member of sysadmin and have effective permission 'VIEW SERVER STATE', but execution of my modified procedure brings the 'The user does not have permission to perform this action' error... I see there logic since  DBO database user by itself doesn't have server permissions (even if Administrator login has). But what next?

I have tried:

1. GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO DBO - doesn't work because  of 'dbo is
   not a user-defined server role' error.
2. Create new user  'ServerStateViewer' linked to 'Administrator' - doesn't work becuase of 'the login already has an account under a different user name' (as I understand it - dbo user exits in the dabatabse)
3. Create new user  'ServerStateViewer' not linked to any login - doesn't work because I can't to add any server permissions to this user.
4. WITH EXECUTE AS 'Administrator' -   doesn't work because of 'Administrator is not a database user'  error.

So it seems I'm forced to create new server login. I am interesting, may be there are still other ways to get WITH EXECUTE AS working under dbo user / Administrator login permissions?

Comment: Who is the database owner?  You?  Sysadmin?

Comment: I believe the SP's caller (as you mentioned) is not relevant.  The SP eliminates the requirement of granting everything to the caller and ownership chaining controls what can be accessed.  As long as the caller can execute it then everything within the SP should fire, provided it's calling objects within its own schema.  The DB owner is who/what establishes the identity of the impersonated user, so it may be failing based on the DB owner.

Comment: @Ben: database owner is Administrator (sql server login 'Administrator'); 'dbo' user is linked to it in my database. My SP WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER returns permission errors in case of any caller: 'Administrator', 'YetAnotherMemberOfSysadminAndDbOwner' etc. Could you propose what kind of caller I should create and test?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use code signing. This is not a problem, since code signing is what you should be using to start with to grant permission to procedures... The proper sequence is this:

- inspect the procedure code to ensure that you trust it
- change the procedure to have an EXECUTE AS OWNER clause
- create a certificate with a private key in the SP's database
- sign the procedure with the private key of the certificate you created
- drop the private key of the certificate (to prevent it from ever being used again)
- copy the certificate into the master database
- create a login from the certificate
- grant AUTHENTICATE SERVER to the certificate derived login
- grant any additional priviledge required by the procedure (e.g. VIEW SERVER STATE) to the certificate derived login

For an example see [Signing an activate procedure](http://rusanu.com/2006/03/01/signing-an-activated-procedure/).

Note that during development code signing can be a pain because *you will have to re-sign the procedure after **every** change to it*. For dev purposes, do not drop the private key right after signing, so it *can* be reused.

Comment: Remus, could I also ask you explain why signing procedure works and why 'just' EXECUTE AS OWNER doesn't work ?

Comment: the link on the first line of my article provides the answer.